# haskell getting parse error on input `->'

Tags: haskell

I am using ghci compiler with version 7.8.3 on windows 7. I am getting error message showing  parse error  on input `->'. I have the following code for lambda expression in haskell.

add =\x y -> x+y

Comment: Note that `=\ ` is an operator. Since you want to assign a lambda expression to the name `add`, you need a space: `= \ `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wrote:

```
add = \x y -> x + y

main = do
    print $ add 1 2
```

and it compiled and output 3.

Unless your intent is to practice unsugared code though, I would write it out as:

```
add x y = x + y
```

Or

```
add = (+)
```

which is "point-free" form.

Answer (score 5):

When defining a function interactively in `ghci`, you have to bind it using a `let` like this:

```
let add = \x y -> x + y
```

Comment: Not if it's globally stated function. If that is the case though, it should just be written in sugared form `add x y = x + y`, or just `add = (+)`.

Comment: Also, the `=` and `\ ` must be separated by space like here, because `=\ ` is a legal operator name.